# How to bind request params without setters?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a simple controller with a GET handler that accepts an object to bind request parameters:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test")
public class SampleController {

    @GetMapping
    public SomeResponse find(RequestParams params) {
       // some code
    }

}
```

The `RequestParams` is a simple POJO class:

```
public class RequestParams  {

    private String param1;
    private String param2;

    // constructor, getter, and setters

}
```

Everthing works fine, but I would like to get rid of the setters to make the object immutable to public use. In the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.2.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments) for `@RequestMapping` handler method up to Spring 5.0.2, we read that 
possible valid method arguments are:

> Command or form objects to bind request parameters to bean properties
>   (via setters) **or directly to fields**

Is it possible to somehow override the default Spring Boot configuration so that request parameters are bound to class properties using reflection and not with setters?

**Update 2018**

In the later versions of Spring's documentation, the quoted statement has been rephrased and no longer contain information about binding request parameters directly to fields.

Comment: Interestingly, no longer see such a statement in that official documentation link.

Comment: But also, I'd expect that for that to work, the fields would have to be public, which defeats the purpose of the request. If they weren't public, and had no setters, I wouldn't expect Spring classes to be able to set the values either?

Comment: Thanks @dbreaux . I've updated question with the link to the latest documentation in which the statement is present. It seems it was removed in version 5.0.3.
My goal was to create a POJO which is at least publicly immutable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In addition to JSON annotations suggested by @jihor you can try to use custom [Web Data binder](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/WebDataBinder.html), adding following code to your controller or to [Controller Advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html) class to span functionality across multiple controllers.

```
@InitBinder
public void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
    binder.initDirectFieldAccess();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot udalmik ! That's what I've been looking for. With `@ControllerAdvice` it works globally for the whole app.

Comment: You rock! Death to getters and setters in DTOs!

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot libraries depend on Jackson (`spring-boot-starter-web`<-`spring-boot-starter-json`<-`jackson libraries`), so one can use its annotations to control json bindings.

`@JsonCreator`-annotated constructors or static methods allow to instantiate objects without explicit setters:

```
@JsonCreator
public RequestParams(@JsonProperty("param1") String param1, 
                     @JsonProperty("param2") String param2) {
    this.param1 = param1;
    this.param2 = param2;
}
```

**Documentation**

- https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html
- https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations/wiki

Comment: Little addition - make sure that there's no empty constructor in class because jackson by default with construct object with it

Comment: I was looking for something like this, because I wanted to use my constructor for instantiating this object.... but without writing custom method argument resolver it is probably not possible. This answer is valid for request object object, not for request parameter object.

btw... JsonProperty annotations are not mandatory with parameters compiler flag.