# Spring MVC (4.3.3) - RestController Get request parameter using direct field access

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Say I have a `RestController`:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("path")
public class MyRestController {
    @GetMapping("path")
    public void myMethod(final MyObject object) throws Exception {
        ...
    }
}
```

By default Spring uses getters and setters to set fields values for the `object` variable.
How can I specify to use direct field access?

I've tried with a custom `Configuration` class, but it doesn't work.

```
@Configuration
public class CustomWebMvcConfigurationSupport extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    protected ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer getConfigurableWebBindingInitializer() {
        final ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer initializer = super.getConfigurableWebBindingInitializer();
        initializer.setDirectFieldAccess(true);
        return initializer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check answer on this SO question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896217/how-to-bind-request-params-without-setters

Comment: I don't have access to those annotations. I'm not using Spring Boot

Comment: So your MyObject has no public setters, and the fields are not public, and you can't change it?

Comment: Fields are public. I solved the problem myself @dbreaux. I'm going to post the answer asap

Comment: @dbreaux posted :) Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working on projects you don't know very well keep an eye on every XML file. When working with a mixture of XML and Java configurations something may not work as expected (especially if you haven't read the Spring documentation carefully).

Basically if you've defined an XML configuration like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans ... [skipped]>
    <description>Spring XML configuration</description>
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.my.package" />
</beans>
```

And you try customizing the web configuration extending `WebMvcConfigurationSupport`:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {
    @Override
    protected ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer getConfigurableWebBindingInitializer() {
        final ConfigurableWebBindingInitializer initializer = super.getConfigurableWebBindingInitializer();
        initializer.setDirectFieldAccess(true);
        return initializer;
    }
}
```

You're basically dealing with two different instances, one created by Spring using the XML description, and one created by `WebMvcConfiguration`.

I solved using only the Java configuration.
So, by coding your `web.xml` file this way, you can delete entirely the XML configuration. You can see I specified I want an Annotation configuration for the `contextClass` parameter, and my configuration class for the `contextConfigLocation` parameter

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    <init-param>
         <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
         <param-value>org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext</param-value>
     </init-param>
     <init-param>
         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>com.my.package.WebMvcConfiguration</param-value>
     </init-param>
</servlet>
```

Remember to add the `@ComponentScan` annotation to the Java class:

```
@ComponentScan("com.my.package")
```