# Getting Null Value from Form Submission

Tags: spring, forms, spring-boot, form-submit, modelattribute

In my current project, I am trying implementing a user registration form, but every time I try submit the user data to the server, the model object is staying with null value.

that's my form:

```
<form class="form-container" id="form" method="post" th:object="${command}" th:action="@{/usuario/register}">
  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-75">
      <input type="text" th:field="*{username}" placeholder="Login"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-75">
      <input type="password" th:field="*{password}" placeholder="Senha"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-75">
      <input type="text" th:field="*{firstName}" placeholder="Nome"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-75">
      <input type="text" th:field="*{lastName}" placeholder="Sobrenome"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-75">
      <input type="email" th:field="*{email}" placeholder="E-mail"/>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="form-row">
    <div class="col-75">
      <button type="button" class="button" onclick="register();">Cadastre-se</button>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="alert-ok" id="ok" style="display: none;">
    <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
    <strong>Sucesso!</strong> Cadastro realizado com sucesso.
  </div>

  <div class="alert-error" id="error" style="display: none;">
    <span class="closebtn" onclick="this.parentElement.style.display='none';">&times;</span>
    <strong>Erro!</strong> Não foi possivel realizar o cadastro.
  </div>
</form>
```

in the controller I have:

```
  @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method=RequestMethod.GET)
  public String formRegister(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("command", new Usuario());
    return "register";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method=RequestMethod.POST)
  @ResponseBody
  public void doRegister(@ModelAttribute("usuario") Usuario object) throws Exception {
    this.serv.register(object);
  }
```

(I also tried: `doRegister(@Valid Usuario object, BindingResult result)` but doesn't work either - same problem)

In my service class, I got this code:

```
  public void register(Usuario novo) throws Exception {
    novo.setEnabled(true);
    novo.setLocked(false);
    novo.setCredenciais(new HashSet<Credencial>());
    Credencial credencial = credencialDao.findBy("nome", "web");
    novo.getCredenciais().add(credencial);
    this.dao.insert(novo);
  }
```

my model class:

```
@Entity
public class Usuario extends Model implements UserDetails {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Integer id;

  @Column
  private String username;

  @Column
  private String password;

  @Column
  private String firstName;

  @Column
  private String lastName;

  @Column
  private String email;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private Set<org.loja.model.credencial.Credencial> credenciais;

  @Column
  private Date dataExpiracao;

  @Column
  private Boolean enabled;

  @Column
  private Boolean locked;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  private org.loja.model.cesta.Cesta cesta;

  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "usuario")
  private Set<org.loja.model.pedido.Pedido> pedidos;
}
```

Anyone can see what's wrong here? I am stuck several hours with this problem, but cannot understand what's causing this issue. I think the code looks very similar with other codes I searched on the web handling the same operation.

**update**

```
function register() {
  var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("form"));
  var url = document.getElementById("form").action;

  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("POST", url);
  xhr.onload = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var result = this.responseText;
    if(result == "")
      document.getElementById("ok").style.display = 'block';
    else
      document.getElementById("error").style.display = 'block';
  };
  xhr.send(formData);
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please attach more information? What does the JavaScript register() function do apart from submitting the form? Have you checked your browser Network console so that you are sure what data you send to the server in the POST request body? Have you checked e. g. https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/ for comparison? There is a simple input submit button instead - have you tried that variant as well?

Comment: @PetrBodnár added the javascript function handling the form submission. And yes, I checked the browser network console, and all the parameters are shown there correctly.

Comment: Also, are you 100% sure that "the model object is staying with null value". Isn't it its fields which stay null ("...with null value**s**")? Then the answer to your question is probably here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896217/how-to-bind-request-params-without-setters/49892623#49892623.

Comment: @PetrBodnár No. I check both each parameter individually (with BindingResult) and the object itself (in the controller). Both are receiving a null value.

Comment: @PetrBodnár And regarding the link  you indicate me, I have a InitBinder  method with PropertyEditorSupport classes for all my model layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this changing the parameter:

```
@ModelAttribute("usuario") Usuario object
```

to:

```
@ModelAttribute("command") Usuario object
```

in a way making the name for ModelAttribute the same of the used in the method `public String formRegister(Model model)`.